# How to time expire Rails fragment caches?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How would I go about expiring a fragment cache after a period of time. I came across references to a `timed_fragment_cache` gem, but it seems out-dated.

Answer (score 88, accepted):

Using [`ActiveSupport::Cache::Store`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html#activesupport-cache-store), you should be able to do

```
<% cache(key, expires_in: 1.hour) do %>
   <!-- content -->
<% end %>
```

Comment: could I expire it automatically ?

Comment: @newBike how do you mean? The snippet means that the content inside the block _will_ automatically expire after 1 hour.

Comment: i meant that guest should visit the page then the cache will be expired, somehow it will block user's request for wait the cache

Comment: Cache it only for registered users, or per user (include user id in the key).